# Installing yum on mac osx 10.8.2. Errors.

Tags: macos, yum

I am trying to install yum on my mac. This is what I am doing.

```
tar -xvzf yum-2.0.7.tar.gz
cd yum-2.0.7
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The last command `sudo make install` runs into the errors below:

```
make -C .. installdirs
./mkinstalldirs /usr/bin /etc /usr/share/yum /usr/man/man8 /usr/man/man5 /var/cache/yum/
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../docs/yum.8 /usr/man/man8/yum.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../docs/yum-arch.8 /usr/man/man8/yum-arch.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../docs/yum.conf.5 /usr/man/man5/yum.conf.5
/usr/bin/install: illegal option -- -
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
/usr/bin/install: illegal option -- -
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
/usr/bin/install: illegal option -- -
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
 /usr/bin/install: illegal option -- -
  usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
  make[1]: *** [install] Error 64
  make: *** [install] Error 2
```

And when I run yum command it says

```
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 22, in <module>
    import yummain
  File "/usr/share/yum/yummain.py", line 22, in <module>
    import clientStuff
  File "/usr/share/yum/clientStuff.py", line 18, in <module>
    import rpm
ImportError: No module named rpm
```

Could someone please help me fixing this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you're looking for. But I would recommend AGAINST you installing yum on your Mac.

[Macports](http://www.macports.org/) and [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) are much better OSX specific alternatives.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. I personally prefer MacPorts, but to each his own. Both MacPorts and Homebrew have extensive, well-tested package collections, are mature projects, and have wide user bases. I actually didn't know `yum` had been ported to OSX until I read your post.